# NSURL Loading data percentage Value

Tags: iphone

I need to read NSURL Loading data percentage value.

That is, I want to read how many percentage amount of data is loading on URL Loading time.

Suppose a URL take 30 seconds to loading data completely, I want to know in 15th sec how many  percentage of data is loading in my String, and 20th sec how many percentage of data is loading in my String, like this I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you will have to use NSURLConnection. In its delegate's implementation include the following method:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSHTTPURLResponse *)response {
    long long contentLength = [response expectedContentLength];
    ...
}
```

Note that the only way to know how many bytes the server is going to return is to retrieve the value from its HTTP response. If you find that `expectedContentLength` returns -1 (and you should be prepared for that), the server does not return a meaningful value for the downloaded content size, perhaps because it doesn't support the feature. In such a case you should resort to alternative ways to get the byte size.

Comment: If you can configure your HTTP server to always send the Content-Length field, you should. Otherwise, you can either display an indeterminate progress indicator or try to create your own server API which would tell you the size of the resource. That said, being prepared to show an indeterminate progress indicator is very useful when you don't have ultimate control of the server.